# Second tap/click on marker doesn't call OnMarkerClickListener

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I've added an OnMarkerClickListener to my map. When I tap on a marker, the OnMarkerClickListener gets invoked and displays an AlertDialog. But, if I cancel out of the AlertDialog and tap on the same marker a second time, the OnMarkerClickListener isn't called.  Here's my OnMarkerClickListener:

```
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

  @Override
  public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
        DirectionsActivity.this);
    builder.setMessage(marker.getSnippet());
    builder.setTitle(marker.getTitle());
    builder.setPositiveButton("Open in Google Maps",
        new OnClickListener() {

          // ...
          }
        });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();

    return false;
  }
});
```

Simply moving or zooming the map allows me to make an additional click on the same marker. Because of this, if my OnMarkerClickListener.onMarkerClick returns `true` then the default handling, which includes centering the map on the clicked marker, is executed and I can make a second click on the same marker, but a third and subsequent clicks don't do anything. So the problem seems to be that a click on the same marker isn't being recognized until the map zoom or center changes.

I'm not doing anything special with my markers except that I do have custom icons derived from bitmaps.

Is anyone else having this problem?  Anything I should check that I might be doing wrong? Or is this a known issue?

Comment: FWIW, this sample app does not demonstrate this problem: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Taps It may be that the dialog is interfering with matters. I would temporarily comment that out and do something less invasive (`Toast`, `Log`, etc.) and see if it works.

Comment: Good idea, and thanks for that sample project.  I tried doing a Toast instead of an Alert, but I still get the same problem. Also, I imported your Taps project and ran it and I'm able to reproduce the same issue there too.  Just to clarify, in your Taps app, I tap on the Carnegie Hall marker and I see the Toast. I wait for the toast to go away and then tap a second time on Carnegie Hall and I see the Toast again. But the third and subsequent taps on Carnegie Hall produce no effect.  However, I've realized that I'm not using the latest google-play-services library, so maybe that's an issue.

Comment: Are you dismissing the info window between taps? I can reproduce your problem if I keep tapping on the marker with the already-open info window. This feels like a bug in Maps V2.

Comment: No. I'm strictly just tapping on the marker. Third and subsequent taps on the marker don't call the OnMarkerClickListener.  But, if I "dismiss" the info window after each marker tap (I do this by tapping somewhere else on the map), then taps on the marker always register. So looks like this is a bug. I'll file a bug report with Google.  Thanks Mark.

Comment: I've already raised a bug for this, I put this thread in the description:

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4829&thanks=4829&ts=1358789849

Please vote on the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to close the loop here, turns out this is a bug.  bbalazs created a bug report here: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4829 but was merged in as a duplicate of this bug report: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4760

You can vote on http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4760 by clicking on its star icon.

Answer (score 0):

In the 'onMarkerClick' method, set return value to 'true'.